# Como inserir no banco de dados o botão carregado

Tags: php, html, mysql

No meu código tenho 3 botões, que servem para o utilizador classificar o serviço:

```
<input type="submit" name="verde" class="verde" value="">
<input type="submit" name="amarelo" class="amarelo" value="">
<input type="submit" name="vermelho" class="vermelho" value="">
```

Como é que ponho no banco de dados, na tabela, o "botão" que ele escolheu para classificar o serviço? Os dados estão a ser inseridos sem problema, só estou a ter problemas em como inserir no campo `classificacao`.

Até agora estou a fazer assim:

```
if (isset($_POST['verde']) || isset($_POST['amarelo']) || isset($_POST['vermelho'])) {
    $inserir=mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO questionario (pergunta_id, pergunta, hora, idioma, origem, classificacao) VALUES ('','$stringarray','$hora','$lang', '','')");
    if (!$inserir) {
        echo "Erro ao inserir na tabela.";
    } else {
        header('location: comentario.php');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definindo a cor no `value` do botão ao invés de `name`:

```
<input type="submit" name="botao" class="verde" value="verde">
<input type="submit" name="botao" class="amarelo" value="amarelo">
<input type="submit" name="botao" class="vermelho" value="vermelho">
```

No `PHP` faz assim apenas:

```
if (isset($_POST['botao'])) {
    $classificacao = $_POST['botao'];
    $inserir=mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO questionario (pergunta_id, pergunta, hora, idioma, origem, classificacao) VALUES ('','$stringarray','$hora','$lang', '','$classificacao')");
    //restante do código
```

Edit com a verificação, sem precisar preencher o `value` dos botões:

```
if (isset($_POST['verde'])){
    $classificacao = $_POST['verde'];
}elseif(isset($_POST['amarelo'])){
    $classificacao = $_POST['amarelo'];
}elseif(isset($_POST['vermelho'])){
    $classificacao = $_POST['vermelho'];
}
if(isset($classificacao)){
    $inserir=mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO questionario (pergunta_id, pergunta, hora, idioma, origem, classificacao) VALUES ('','$stringarray','$hora','$lang', '','$classificacao')");
    //restante do código
```

Comment: Muito obrigada! Eu só não tinha posto nada em `value` pois não quero que apareça nenhum texto, mas pronto isso é o minimo! Obrigada, funcionou!

Comment: Você pode tbm fazer um verificador no `PHP` para esse caso de não querer que apareça texto, se quiser posso editar com uma forma de fazer essa verificação

Comment: Seria ótimo da sua parte Wees!

Comment: Prontinho @Ana, editei a resposta

Comment: Obrigada Wees, eu tentei sem por nada no `value` entretanto não deu, só funciona se estiver algo dentro de `value`

Comment: Eu resolvi isso com css, agora está tudo otimo, obrigada mais uma vez!